# While implementing cupertino modal sheet using sheet package, the following animation cannot be implemented

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a student who recently started learning flutter.

I'm trying to implement cupertino BottomSheet using a package called sheet, but I can't implement an animation that makes the background screen smaller.

[Example.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diemq.gif)
[My Result.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DNPI.gif)

```dart
Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CupertinoPageScaffold(
```

I also configured the screen that calls the bottom sheet as above, but this did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.